# Xcode10 random popup "The bundle identifier for XCode10Project.app couldn’t be read."

Tags: ios, xcode10, xcode10beta6

I've created a project in  XCode10 Beta6. I closed the project and opened another project from XCode 9.2 At random points throughout working on another project, I get alert popup saying.

**How do I resolve "The bundle identifier for XCode10Project.app couldn’t be read."** issue with XCode10 Beta 6?

the popup appears every time after I test my xcode 9.2 project
[image]

Comment: I've seen this and I can't remember how I fixed it. Basically I'd suggest this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to delete derived data and clean project, as described here: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later/6247073#6247073)

Deleting the offending project from disk will not fix it.

Comment: Now that Xcode 10 is out of beta, this is more of a workaround than a solution.. Looking for the cause still

Comment: I added a UI Test Target and while running Test target I was facing a similar issue. clear derived data solves my issue.